# Copying USB files to local Linux folder

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer

How do I copy files from a USB flash drive in Ubuntu Linux from command line?  When I copy these files from USB to a local folder I get "permissions denied" using the GUI.

On the command line I can use `sudo`, but how do I become a super user using the GUI?

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu, all USB drives, once mounted, are in the `/media` directory

```
cp /media/your-usb/file-in-usb ~
```

That copies a file on your USB disk to the user's home directory, assuming the drive is called `your-usb` and the file is `file-in-usb`.

I am not sure why you need permissions to copy from the USB to a local file. Maybe you don't have permission to access the USB or you are trying to copy them to a directory where you don't have permissions. I would do this to find the permissions of the files on the USB drive:

```
ls -l /media/your-usb/
```

Post the result of this and the directory you are trying to copy the files to.

I don't recommend running the GUI file manager under super user privileges, but this but this is how you would launch Nautilus in root mode:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You can simply use cp command to copy  files.Usually any media will be mounted in /media/nameofusb/.
    inorder to copy a file you can use

> cp

[image]

and 
to copy a directory you can use

> cp -r

[image]

2)That is unusual.But you can try to remount the usb as rw as superuser by this command

> mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1

here my device is sdb1.Make changes accordingly.I hope this works.

3)You should see something like this.
[image]

but since you are using ubuntu, you can go to terminal,login as su and type

> startx

to launch a xserver session for root.In this session you will get all the root privilages on nautilus.